# Output Media is outputted to 2 Directories instead of 1

Tags: javascript, npm-scripts

## Issue

Ive been trying to convert a series of images, PNG to JPG, and I seem to run into an issue where the output media is outputted to the intended path and the path of the code main script:

module used: [npm media-converter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/media-converter)

### Code:

```
/**
 * Reads PNG File(s) then converts to JPG
 */
function ArrayConvertPNGtoJPG() {

    // PNG to JPG Spinner
    const pngTOjpgSpinner = ora("WARNING: Attempting Conversion of PNG to JPG").start();

    const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, './Input');
    setTimeout(() => {
        fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
            //handling error
            if (err) {
                return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
            } 
    
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const input = "./Input/" + files[i];
                const output = `./Converted/${files[i].slice(0, -4)}.jpg`
                convert(input, output, (err) => {
                    if (!err){
                      pngTOjpgSpinner.succeed("SUCCESS: ".green + input.green + " Converted to ".green + output.green);
                    } else {
                        pngTOjpgSpinner.fail("ERROR: Unable to convert file: " + input + " to a JPG");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

### Result:

[image]

If you could help me find a solution it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a, possibly intended?, feature of the media-converter.

First, is willl try to convert the .png to .jpg and output that in the `/Converted` folder.

Second, it will try to compress the resulting .jpg using the `imagemin` package.

In the code in `node_modules/media-converter/converter.js`, you will find the line:

```
destination: './'
```

Meaning, the destination of the `/Converted/my-image.jpg` file, once it has been compressed, will be the root folder of the installation. That is why you see the converted but uncompressed file in `/Converted/my-image.jpg` and the converted AND compressed file in the root of the installation.

Nothing you can do about that, unless you wait for the plugin to get updated (I see you already filed an issue, so it might be resolved some time in the future).

Or you can fiddle with the plugin code and change the destination for the compressed version. (Note, it cannot be the same folder `./Converted/`, it must be something else or the plugin errors.)

```
destination: './Converted/Compressed/',
```

(Still, you have two files as a result. You can write some code to delete the files in `/Converted/` and copy those in `./Converted/Compressed/` to `./Converted`. Whatever suits your needs.)

Comment: I see you took your time out to help me. and I tried putting it in a different directory and it still outputted to the root folder. I have set functions to estimate the waiting time for the process to be finished and it works 80% of the time. Since I can't do anything about this issue I'll learn Js fully and replicate my own module

Comment: You deserve the 50